# Silverlight 5 print fail with high DPI

Tags: silverlight, printing, silverlight-5.0

I'm using Silverlight 5 and PrintDocument in order to print document (with one bitmap image and several TextBox).

If I try to create a PDF (for example with CutePDF) A4 with 600 DPI, everything is ok, the PDF file is generated.

But if i try to create A1 with 600 DPI, nothing happens, print job is not created as well as the PDF file. If I try A1 with 72 or 144 DPI, then it works.

What could be a problem? Silverlight has some limit?

Thanks in advance.